# SEO-friendly HTACCESS 301 redirect for non-www to www PLUS .php to non-.php PLUS http to htps

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a custom build non-CMS site on PHP.

The way my current .htaccess is setup is to allow me to use the urls without ".php" part and to 301 redirect all non www requests to www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Now we are switching to HTTPS.

How do I get a proper SEO-friendly redirect from `http://` to `https://` in .htaccess?

I've tried replacing third string with

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't do the trick...

Also, optionally, is there a way to set up a 301 redirect for .php request to redirect to non-.php variant? Although it looks like it means to redirect to same exact page, not sure if it will be SEO-safe to do it or maybe it will even result in a redirect loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following htaccess rules (just replace `example\.com` with `yourdomain\.com` in the second RewriteCond)

```
RewriteEngine On


#301 redirect from http to https + non-www to www
RewriteCond ℅{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_HOST} (?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.℅1℅{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]

#remove .php extension
#redirect to remove .php from URLs
RewriteCond ℅{THE_REQUEST} /(.+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /℅1 [L,R=301]
#handle extension less php URLs
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I've tried the first part (301 redirect from http to https + non-www to www), but it only redirects non-www to www, and no http to https is observed.

Comment: actually even worse - it is redirects all the pages to root domain...

Comment: @Acidon Try cleaning your browser cache.